# Round the edges of 3D Pie chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, 3d, pie-chart

I have created a 3D pie chart using d3.js. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/crazyCoder1989/qkHK6/3009/) is what I achieved so far. I need smoother or rounded edges for the graph similar to this picture.(Image is only for reference purpose).

I'm using d3 version 4.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Before putting any more effort in creating complex 3D pie charts, I suggest to read a little about effective visualizations. For example [here](https://www.darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/salvaging-the-pie) or [here](http://www.perceptualedge.com/example12.php).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These documents gives information about how well can we present the graph. Thanks a lot for this info.But there is code mentioned in these sites.Can you please help me in solving my problem :-)